# Android: How to know when an activity finish?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have a `main activity A` -> `call activity B` -> `call activity C` -> `call activity D`.

Activity is called by `startActivity(intent).`
`Activity D` have a "Close" button.

How to I notify to `Activity A` when hit "close" button on `Activity D`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? At the point you close Activity D, it will simple return to Activity C and Activities B & A will remain on the back stack in a stopped state. In a worse case scenario, if system resources are low, Activities B and/or A may have even been destroyed by the system to free up memory.

Comment: -Two ways
1.)Making you own listener [Custom listener] you can notify you main activity
2.) using getter setter method and creating boolean object You can get value of boolean in you main activity

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Use SharedPreference to store the status of button in Activity D.

In activity A under onResume() get the status of button from the SharedPreference.

Answer (score 1):

```
   //* start the activity with enum defined int activity D to identify your activity
   startActivityForResult(intent, DActivity.D_REQUEST_CODE);

  //in your D activity define this
  private static final int D_REQUEST_CODE  = 1;


  //* when the button is clicked to close in your D activity, call this in the button event listner
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);


  //* implement this in your A activity
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    if(data==null)return;
    if (requestCode == DActivity.D_REQUEST_CODE) 
    {
      switch (resultCode) 
      {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
           //* do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    findViewById(R.id.button_close).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_A.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }
    });
```

This will work if you are looking to simply show Activity A while clearing the activity stack. If you just want to know when you return to Activity A, you can save status in SharedPrefs as answered above.